# Minikube: Unable to start minikube - Exiting due to DRV_NO_IP:

Tags: minikube

I am trying to create the minikube cluster, but It always fails.

Any suggestions are very welcome:

C:\WINDOWS\system32>minikube start --driver=vmware

- minikube v1.16.0 on Microsoft Windows 10 Home 10.0.19042 Build 19042
- Using the vmware driver based on user configuration
- Starting control plane node minikube in cluster minikube
- Creating vmware VM (CPUs=2, Memory=4000MB, Disk=20000MB) ...
- Deleting "minikube" in vmware ...
  ! StartHost failed, but will try again: creating host: create: Error creating machine: Error in driver during machine creation: Machine didn't return an IP after 120 seconds, aborting
- Creating vmware VM (CPUs=2, Memory=4000MB, Disk=20000MB) ...
- Failed to start vmware VM. Running "minikube delete" may fix it: creating host: create: Error creating machine: Error in driver during machine creation: Machine didn't return an IP after 120 seconds, aborting

X Exiting due to DRV_NO_IP: Failed to start host: creating host: create: Error creating machine: Error in driver during machine creation: Machine didn't return an IP after 120 seconds, aborting

- Suggestion: Check your firewall rules for interference, and run 'virt-host-validate' to check for KVM configuration issues. If you are running minikube within a VM, consider using --driver=none
- Documentation: https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/reference/drivers/kvm2/
- Related issues:

  - https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/4249
  - https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/3566

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar error when setting up Minikube on Mac OS.

When I run the command `minikube start` I get the error below:

```
  minikube v1.22.0 on Darwin 11.4
✨  Using the vmware driver based on existing profile
  Starting control plane node minikube in cluster minikube
  Updating the running vmware "minikube" VM ...
  StartHost failed, but will try again: provision: IP not found for MAC 00:0c:29:41:e9:b9 in DHCP leases
  Updating the running vmware "minikube" VM ...
  Failed to start vmware VM. Running "minikube delete" may fix it: provision: IP not found for MAC 00:0c:29:41:e9:b9 in DHCP leases

❌  Exiting due to GUEST_PROVISION: Failed to start host: provision: IP not found for MAC 00:0c:29:41:e9:b9 in DHCP leases
```

The issue was caused by an interruption when I was creating the VMWare VM for  Minikube.

I tried fixing it by deleting the existing minikube vm and creating another one using:

```
minikube delete
minikube start
```

But then I ran into another issue this time:

> Exiting due to DRV_NO_IP: Failed to start host: creating host: create: Error creating machine: Error in driver during machine creation: Machine didn't return an IP after 120 seconds, aborting.

**Here's how I fixed it**

After multiple research, it's just best to set up **minikube** with **docker** driver which will save you all this hassle.

**For Mac OS**:

If you already have docker installed or docker-compose simply uninstall it using:

```
brew uninstall docker
brew uninstall docker-compose
```

Next, install **Docker desktop**. This will install **Docker/Docker Desktop**, **Docker-compose** and other dependencies using:

```
brew install --cask docker
```

Next, start the docker engine by opening the Docker application. Afterwhich you can confirm the docker version using:

```
docker --version
```

Finally, setup minikube using docker driver:

```
minikube start --driver=docker
```